# Android System Alert Window turns off and on periodically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I have an application that creates a System Alert Window through a service.

In `MainActivity` I instantiate the Intent:

```
i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TintOverlayService.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

In TintOverlayService, I am creating the System Alert Window like so:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

mTopView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.red_overlay, null);

mTopView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode.replace("#", tintValue)));

DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;

    int LayoutParamFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            densityDpi * 6,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            LayoutParamFlags,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

And the onStartCommand override of TintOverlayService returns:

```
return START_STICKY;
```

This successfully creates a full overlay on the screen, to the edges. Even when outside of the app, as intended.

However, when you activate the overlay and kill the app. The overlay blinks for a second or two and starts up again. Or, if you're just using the phone normally browsing the internet or watching a video... the overlay will shut off anywhere between a couple seconds to 30 seconds and then turn back on.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction would be helpful. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

When you kill the app, the service is also killed. With  START_STICKY set as return value, the system will try to start up the service again as soon as possible (when it has enough memory).
That results in the service creating the overlay again.
If you want to prevent this, it should be enough, to change the return value to START_NOT_STICKY.

Is killing the app part of the functionality of your app or just you stress testing it?

**EDIT**
Disappearing and appearing again might be the result of the system stopping your service (thinking it is no longer needed), and START_STICKY leading to the service being started again.
I circumvented a similar problem by triggering a service start every X minutes. The following code is written simply from memory and I cannot test it right now, so it might include some errors.

```
public class OverlayService extends Service{
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
boolean isKeepAliveActive = false;


@Override
public void onCreate(){

//DO YOUR STUFF
initKeepAlive();
startKeepAlive();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

String action = intent.getAction() == null ? "empty": intent.getAction();
if (action.equals("KeepAlive")){
    //KEEP ALIVE TRIGGER, NOTHING TO DO
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
else if (action.equals("WHATEVER")){
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}

//DO YOUR STUFF

return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
stopKeepAlive();
super.onDestroy();
}

private void initKeepAlive(){
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        private void run(){
            try{
                isKeepAliveActive = true;

                //Get context of your service and the class name of your service
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, OverlayService.class);
                intent.setAction("KeepAlive");
                context.startService(intent);

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20*60*1000);
            } catch (Exception e){
                isKeepAliveActive = false;
            }
        }

private void startKeepAlive(){
    if (!isKeppAliveActive){
        runnable.run();
    }

private void stopKeepAlive(){
    if (isKeepAliveActive){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        isKeepAliveActive = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Killing it was just stress testing it. I kind of assumed that is the case when killing the app. What worries me the most is when you're just using the phone normally and the overlay gets killed and starts up again. I am not sure if there is a way to patch that, or just a silly android thing.

Comment: What behavior do you want? If the overlay should remain removed when the app is killed/crashed, START_NOT_STICKY should solve this problem.

Comment: I want it to stay. The issue is that it shuts off and turns back on periodically. Even when not killing the app. So, you turn on the overlay and switch into some other app or start browsing the internet. Eventually, the overlay will turn on and off.

Comment: I editted my answer. The behavior is most likely coming from system killing the (assumed) idling service and the service then restarting because of START_STICKY.

Comment: Awesome! I will try this tonight and let you know how it goes! It is always the simple things you never try. Thanks!